# Screen or canvas not updated for Inkscape on Debian bookworm and XFCE

Tags: debian, xfce, inkscape

I encounter a problem with Inkscape on Debian bookworm with XFCE and X11.
I ask my question here because I suspect that the problem might be linked to something else than Inkscape (compositor maybe?).

It is illustrated in [this screen capture](https://ufile.io/lr46xikb).

1. I draw a rectangle → everything fine
2. I Select the text tool, click on the canvas and type some text →
   nothing displayed / normally the letters should have appeared on
   the canvas
3. Click and drag to create a text box, write some text → nothing
   displayed / same expectations
4. I open the text options → the text previously typed in 2 and 3 is now
   displayed on canvas
5. Click and write some more text → again, the canvas is not updated
6. click on the separator between canvas and options (as if to resize
   the options box) → the text typed in step 5 appears on the canvas
7. Close the options → the canvas is not updated, the pixels of the
   options box remain displayed, although the box is no longer "there".

My understanding so far is that the problem is with how the screen is (not) updated. The bug is especially obvious in step 7. I couldn't find a bug report describing this problem for Inkscape, therefore I think that it is linked to something in my configuration. Where could I start looking ? Could it be something related to X11 vs Wayland ?
My video card is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some poking, I found [this bug](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/3664), also referenced [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1034289). Short answer: I had `xim` set as input method in XFCE. With the following, the problem disappeared:

`unset GTK_IM_MODULE && inkscape`

For a permanent fix, I unset the Input method in XFCE's settings menu.